# Creating custom window buttons - Chrome for Desktop

Tags: google-chrome-app

How can I customise the icons that are visible in the top right hand corner for a Chrome for Desktop app as in Weather Bug? I couldn't find any related APIs.

[image: Weather bug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set frame type 'none' and build them yourself.

Comment: Oh that's so obvious now that you mention it. They clearly aren't native elements!